# Swifui background color is not changing

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a very simple screen I just need to change background color of screen

My code

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            
            Text("Hey! Welcome")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text("We deliver on-demand fresh fruits directly from your nearby farms.")
                .font(.body)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray).padding(1)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Get Started").foregroundColor(Color.black).fontWeight(.medium).padding(10)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: screenWidth * 0.875)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("I already have an account").foregroundColor(Color.black).fontWeight(.medium).padding(10)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: screenWidth * 0.875)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

If i use `Color.purple.ignoresSafeArea()` next to or inside VStack its changing color but my text etc all things are going to bottom

[image]

I just need to change my background color and make the box transparent its showing white with purple.

Comment: The layout issue is caused by a parent view and isn't shown in the code you've included. If you include a [mre], we may be able to debug it. Unrelated to your issue, but be aware that using `UIScreen.main.bounds` like this is potentially fragile -- you may want to just use `.padding` instead of trying to base your margins on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this work for me.

```
struct BackgroundClearView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Example:

```
VStack{
            GenderVW(showModal: .constant(true), selectedGender: .constant(Gender(id: 0, gender: "Male")))
        }.background(BackgroundClearView())
```

Answer (score 0):

try something simple like this, using a `ZStack` and adjusting the color you want:

```
    ZStack {
        Color.purple.ignoresSafeArea() // <--- here the background color
        VStack {
          Text("Hey! Welcome")
          ...
        }
    }
```